# How to integrate Facebook without redirect Safari browser in iOS app with latest FBSDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

Hi i am search the answer for avoid new facebooksdk redirect to safari.how to open facebook login view inside the app.if it redirect to safari may reject in app store? help me.. thanks in advance

Comment: I updated my answer please check

Answer (score 17, accepted):

yesterday I submit my app to store using `FBSDKLoginManager` using three kinds of Login with Facebook , actually Facebook follow the first three conditions automatically

**Type -1**

if the user already installed the Facebook native app the details will be retrieved from the app.

**Type -2**

if the user does't have the Facebook app, but he is logged in at the device's Settings, the user details will be taken from those.

**Type -3**

if none of the condition above is satisfied the user will be automatically redirected to `Safari`.

**Type -4**

```
    if you none of the above three conditions is relevant for you please continue below code.
```

> apple does not reject your app

**Objective-C**

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;  // it open inside the app using popup menu
```

**Swift**

```
var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Native
```

**FBSDKLoginBehavior Types**

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FBSDKLoginBehavior)
{
  /*!
@abstract Attempts log in through the native Facebook app. If the   Facebook app is
not installed on the device, falls back to \c  FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser. This is the
default behavior.
*/
 FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative = 0,
/*!
@abstract Attempts log in through the Safari browser
  */
FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser,
 /*!
  @abstract Attempts log in through the Facebook account currently signed in through Settings.
   If no Facebook account is signed in, falls back to \c FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative.
   */
 FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount,
  /*!
   @abstract Attemps log in through a modal \c UIWebView pop up

   @note This behavior is only available to certain types of apps. Please check the Facebook
   Platform Policy to verify your app meets the restrictions.
   */
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb,
   };
```

the new concept

[Facebook SDK for iOSv4.x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etI4k.png)

> (v4.6.0 - September 10, 2015) In addition, the SDK dialogs such as Login, Like, Share Dialogs automatically determine the best UI based on the device, including SFSafariViewController instead of Safari. Follow the our Preparing for iOS 9 guide.

you can get like

[image]

Comment: FBSDKLoginManager to use share dialog is possible

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik:possible to get invited friends list from fbsdk

Comment: @priya -- // For more complex open graph stories, use `FBSDKShareAPI`
// with `FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent`
/* make the API call */
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/me/invitable_friends"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];

Comment: @priya -- need ref this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.4

Answer (score 8):

When your select login behavior is `FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb`, Then open webView popUp.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
```

PopUp Facebook :

[image]

**Note :** when facebook behavior is `FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser` then its always redirect on safari browser. Change its behavior to `FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb`.

Use This For Latest Update from FB SDK

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
    NSArray *userdetails;
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:userdetails fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login Error : %@", error.description);
        }
        else if(result.isCancelled)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login Cancel By User");
        }
        else
        {
            //[self fetchUserDataForFacebookLogin];
            //[login logOut];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: This is useful, the new login flow is terrible and the analytics back it up. This at least eliminates users already logged into Safari to continue. This their whole new schema is terrible UX.

Comment: as per latest policy of Facebook, only specific type of apps can only use this behaviour. The answer should have a note on this.

Answer (score 3):

In swift 
When your select login behavior is Web, Then open webView popUp.

```
 // Try to login with permissions
        let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

        fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web
```

Answer (score 2):

Just open the Facebook Developer site [http://facebookdevelopers.com](http://facebookdevelopers)
there you will get the whole procedure to integrate facebook in your application without redirecting to Safari browser.

Answer (score 1):

Here i use the code like:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
 @UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
 var window: UIWindow?
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {    
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
 }
}
```

**LoginViewController.swift**

```
 //MARK: FacebookLogin Button
@IBAction func btnFacebookLoginClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logOut()
    fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web //Without safari Browser
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email")){
                self.getFBUserData()
                fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }
        }else if result.isCancelled {
        print("Cancelled")
    }
    })
}

func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                self.facebookUserDict = result as! NSDictionary
                print(result)
                print(self.facebookUserDict)
            print(self.facebookUserDict.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as! String)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**But what if I am not using `FBSDKLoginManager`...?**

But what if I do not implement a Facebook login method in my ViewController and I am just using the `FBSDKLoginButton` Facebook SDK touch upside action outlet implementation to login, which by default uses the Safari browser?

How do I change the `FBSDKLoginBehavior`?

If you are using the `FBSDKLoginButton` without your own Touch Up Inside action outlet, aka, you just added a UIButton or UIView to your Storyboard and changed its type to `FBSDKLoginButton` and that was enough, when the UI Component was touched to get Safari Facebook Authentication working...

To change `FBSDKLoginBehavior` simply add an Outlet in your ViewController to your Storyboard `FBSDKLoginButton` and set `loginBehavior`, no need to use `FBSDKLoginManager`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnFbSignIn: FBSDKLoginButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    btnFbSignIn.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.web
}
```

Comment: I need your help.