# Social Media Login in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, uiwebview

In my iOS app, I am opening a URL in a `UIWebView`. On the webpage, there is an option to login through social media like Facebook, Google, Twitter etc.

But when I click on the login through say Facebook option, I see a blank screen. What happens is that, it opens a pop-up in the same `UIWebView` instance. But I am not sure why I see a blank screen.

The URL works well if I use Safari on my device.

Can you please guide what options on `UIWebView` shall I enable that the pop-ups work. Also I feel that the pop-up(for FB Login) will throw a callback on the initial page. So please help me how should I handle the call back.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to implement Login With Facebook, Twitter?

Comment: If the popup is the main problem (and it likely is, because most webview implementations don’t handle them well from what I’ve heard so far), then I’d recommend that you implement the [manual login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.4), that does not use popups, but rather redirects in the already existing window.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311125/how-to-integrate-facebook-without-redirect-safari-browser-in-ios-app-with-latest/31311184#31311184