# Facebook SDK- 3.24.0 How to prevent app from being redirected to Safari

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I used Facebook SDK version 3.24 for Facebook Login, but my app got rejected as it is redirected to Safari to Login. How can I prevent the app from being redirected to Safari using same version i.e 3.24. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: see this link if you follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311125/how-to-integrate-facebook-without-redirect-safari-browser-in-ios-app-with-latest/31311184#31311184) and the behavior of Facebook login and submit your app the apple don't reject your app

Comment: now apple has changed the rules to login with any social login ,if you want to login with any social login use only inside the app, don't redirect to out of app just look that link and change the build and updated to app store , your app does not reject

Comment: hey what if i want to do login with facebook to open facebook app also by the way?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks for the suggestion. I tried with the link you gave me but it din't work for old version of facebook SDK. I would like to know how I can do that using 3.24.0

Comment: if you need the old model goto your .plist --> remove the URL Schema --> then build your app , it does not redirect your app in outside

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thank you.This works fine, but the solution doesn't solve my problem completely. Web View should be shown only when the Facebook App is not installed in my device. It has to login through facebook app instead of Web view when the facebook app is already installed.

Comment: No if you follow my comments it does not consider the facebook app is install or not else part the session is maintain or not . It does not consider anything. How many you click that button it show the popup