# How to Open Social App Login within application using URL Scheme

Tags: ios, facebook-login, url-scheme, login-control, google-signin

I have seen examples and stack overflow questions that describe this things.

Problem is,

*Apple Rejects Application if I Open Social Login in safari.*

*Most of examples are related to Opening Social Login with safari but not exactly how I want it.*

I want to use Facebook SDK and Open Login Popup within Application.

I think this can be achieved using URL Scheme handling but I don’t know how to do this.

I have seen that Facebook Provides
 FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb (Thank you @Anbu.Karthik for Notify me this thing)

But other apps like Google, Instagram, Twitter, Linked In and other are also need to integrate within app. 
So It would be better if is there any general behavior of application that redirects URL to Open in Webview within application.

Thanks in advanced,

Comment: No one is going to write code for you! and demanding it like it is our job is ridiculous!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate Facebook without redirect Safari browser in iOS app with latest FBSDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311125/how-to-integrate-facebook-without-redirect-safari-browser-in-ios-app-with-latest)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks for sharing nice example, but one of SDK I have seen FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb is not present.

Comment: @Dharmik -- you using which verions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are right, You need to customize URL Scheme handling little bit.

[Here is example code](https://github.com/dharmikvyas/iOSFBLoginPopup/)

Basically You need to add Principle UIApplication class in .pList file as bellow Image and add notification center when you get URL login for your app ID.
[image]

and than, (Application.m)

```
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url {
    if ([[url absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"https://m.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?sdk_version="]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ApplicationAuthNotificationFB object:url];

        return NO;
    }
    return [super openURL:url];
}
```

and
Register Notification in your ViewController, (ViewController.m)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(callLoginPopup:)
                                                 name:@"ApplicationAuthNotificationFB"
                                               object:nil];
```

Method to handle URL (ViewController.m)

```
-(void)callLoginPopup:(NSNotification *)notif{
    NSLog(@"URL To Handle ===> %@", [notif object]);
}
```

You can modify this example to achieve other social login within your app.