# Navigate to previous view controller with default back button not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I would like to navigate from one ViewController to another and after that by the help of navigation controller I would like to navigate to pervious view controller with by default back button.

Problem is:

On the login screen I added a button register here by clicking it application navigate to next viewController, After that again it wont navigate back to login page with using by default back button.

Comment: You should show us the code you've already got if any (if not, search Stack Overflow for how to achieve this), and then ask a specific question about the problem with the code you're having :)

Comment: Actually i have only design view controllers and nothing write to switch one view to another  .i just want to switch one view to another and go back to the pervious view..

Answer (score 1):

just add the `UINavigationController` in your `rootViewController`, just like

[image]

follow the Step `Select` your `RootViewController` -- > select `XCode Menu` --> `Editor` --> `Embed In` - > `Navigation Controller`  follow the image for work flow , if you add this,  the `back button` default  works

[image]

Comment: But my root view controller is login and i want to add back button on register view controller

Comment: @HarshRajput -- if you embed the login viewcontroller to navigation controller , then when you click the login button it goes signup page , when   you click the back button it default comes to back , the stack automatically works

Comment: yeah..it works ..Thanks..One another problem is in integrate Facebook login and i want when login than it comes to the home view .Could u tell me code??

Comment: @HarshRajput -- the facebook default function is this , in which view controller u use the facebook on that viewcontroller it redirects , if my answer is fine give upvote for the answer, ref this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311125/how-to-integrate-facebook-without-redirect-safari-browser-in-ios-app-with-latest/31311184#31311184

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik--i have reached my question limit .Could u  give answer of my second question??