# Facebook login button does not go to Safari, but goes to app instead, then glitches back

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift3

I'm not sure how to replicate the bug consistently yet, but it happens sometimes when I delete the app and reinstall it on a device:

So once in a while when I login with the Facebook button. the Facebook app opens.  Usually the way it works is that it is suppose to open the facebook browser on safari.

Anyway it opens the Facebook app, and then goes back to my app without doing anything. And it just keeps doing that over and over every time I press the login button until I delete my app and redownload it. Is anybody else experiencing that? I am using Swift 3.

Here is a gif of the problem:

[Gif of Facebook login problem](http://tinypic.com/r/33lm7et/9)

and here is my code for the Facebook login:

```
fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], from: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil){
            print(error)

            let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
            loginManager.logOut()
            var controller:LoginController
            controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginController") as! LoginController
            SCLAlertView().showWarning("Login Error #23", subTitle: "Could not log you in, this one is on facebook")
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("logging in")

        }
    }
```

Comment: you can do using set  behaviour of FBSDKLoginManager to FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb. ans also refer following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311125/how-to-integrate-facebook-without-redirect-safari-browser-in-ios-app-with-latest

Answer (score 1):

There are serval behavior options to login with Facebook SDK, you can choose one by setting `loginBehavior`property of `fbLoginManager`:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FBSDKLoginBehavior) {
  /*!
  */
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative = 0, /*!
  */
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser, /*!
  */
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount, /*!
  */
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb,
};
```

In your case, you can set it to `FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser`, an example could be :

```
func fbLogin(){
    //firstly check whether system fb account available, if so use it
    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook){
        fbLoginManger.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.SystemAccount
    }
    //then check whether fb app available, if so open it
    else if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "fb://")!){
        fbLoginManger.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Native
    }
    //lastly, present a popup web inside app
    else{ 
        fbLoginManger.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web
    }

    fbLoginManger.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"], fromViewController: self) { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
       ...
    }
```