# Facebook SDK with iOS swift not open in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using Xcode 8.2.1 and FBSDK 4.19.0
I want to open login in with Facebook in a web view instead of Safari.

This is my `ViewController`:

```
`import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!

    var result:NSDictionary=[:]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loginButton.delegate = self

        if (FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil{
            fetchProfile()
        }

    }

    func fetchProfile(){
    let parameters = ["fields": "name, gender, email, picture.type(large)"]
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                if(error == nil)
                {
                    self.result = result as! NSDictionary
                    print(self.result)
                }
                else
                {
                    print("error \(error)")
                }
            })

    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        print("completed login")

    }
    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

    }

    func loginButtonWillLogin(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

`

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311125/how-to-integrate-facebook-without-redirect-safari-browser-in-ios-app-with-latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the loginBehaviour to .web for FBSDKLoginManager object.

```
let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
loginManager.loginBehaviour = .web
```

Since you are using `FBSDKLoginButton`, in `viewDidLoad` method, write

```
loginButton.loginBehaviour = .web
```