# Resetting Facebook login

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-login

In my app as of now, I have an email/password login. After the user logs in using this method, I would like the user to be able to login using Facebook to access their friends. Currently I have built in the Facebook login button in my application. My application is user-based, so there is login/signup. I store the user's data into Firebase. To explain my problem, I'm going to use person A and person B. Let's say person A signs in to the app and uses the Facebook login(Let me make it clear that the Facebook login is after the app login). Then if person B tries to login and then use the Facebook login, it will say that person B is already logged in(to person A's account). How do I reset the Facebook login for each user?

Here is my code for the login button

```
struct UserService {
static func create(_ firUser: FIRUser, username: String, completion: @escaping (User?) -> Void) {
    let userAttrs = ["username": username]

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(firUser.uid)
    ref.setValue(userAttrs) { (error, ref) in
        if let error = error {
            assertionFailure(error.localizedDescription)
            return completion(nil)
        }

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let user = User(snapshot: snapshot)
            completion(user)
        })
    }
}
static func createFacebookID(_ firUser: FIRUser, facebookID: String, completion: @escaping (User?) -> Void) {
    let userAttrs = ["facebookID": facebookID]

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(firUser.uid).childByAutoId();
    ref.setValue(userAttrs) { (error, ref) in
        if let error = error {
            assertionFailure(error.localizedDescription)
            return completion(nil)
        }

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let user = User(snapshot: snapshot)
            completion(user)
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my createFacebookID function that is in another class

```
static func createFacebookID(_ firUser: FIRUser, facebookID: String, completion: @escaping (User?) -> Void) {
    let userAttrs = ["facebookID": facebookID]

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(firUser.uid).childByAutoId();
    ref.setValue(userAttrs) { (error, ref) in
        if let error = error {
            assertionFailure(error.localizedDescription)
            return completion(nil)
        }

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let user = User(snapshot: snapshot)
            completion(user)
        })
    }
}
```

If you need more information feel free to ask for some. Thanks in advance for taking your time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common bug in the SDK discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092175/how-to-completely-logout-of-facebook-sdk-auth-in-ios-app) among other places.  The solution is to use:

fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = .web