# issue switching FB users in FBSDK in Swift

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app which uses FB login inside the app to gather a users FB id which I use to create a link to their FB page like so:

```
    @IBAction func saveFacebookDidTap(_ sender: Any) {
    if sharingFacebook == false {
        if  FBSDKAccessToken.current() == nil {
            print("no token")
        }
            login.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil && !(result?.isCancelled)! {
                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!

                if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("public_profile") {
                    print("success")
                    let parameters = ["fields" : "id"]

                    if FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil {

                        self.facebookButton.setTitle("Remove Facebook from your Profile", for: [])
                        self.sharingFacebook = true
                    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).start { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                        if error != nil {
                            return
                        }

                        let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]

                        if let id = data["id"] as? NSString{

    //do stuf with the id
```

I also allow the user to remove this FB link like so:

```
    else {
        self.sharingFacebook = false
        self.facebookButton.setTitle("Add Facebook to your Profile", for: [])

        FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()

    }
```

I am having an issue with the FB login page. When the user clicks to add their FB, I am seeing a page that says "You previously logged in to "app name" with Facebook. Would you like to continue?" I am not seeing the fields which let me enter email and password. Any ideas what I could be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having a similar problem. The cause is explained here: [How to completely Logout of Facebook SDK Auth in iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092175/how-to-completely-logout-of-facebook-sdk-auth-in-ios-app)

I was able to get around this issue by setting the Login Behavior, i.e.

```
LoginManager.setLoginBehavior('web');
```

before initiating login.

Comment: The new syntax is `fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = .web`

Comment: @StephanePaquet that resolved the issue by prompting them each log in attempt with blank for FB user/pass... Why is it so hard to just get it to populate the fields and let user edit if needed. I don't like either option.

Comment: I just tested dribble and their facebook login is broken altogether. Tested Pinterest and it has same issue as OP. If i have to choose between the 3 issues ill choose the initial issue posted by OP and seen in pintrest.

Comment: Resent Facebook sdk only supporting through browser. I think clearing safari history in Iphone settings is only way.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when Safari was caching the Facebook login credentials. Went to Settings...Safari...Clear History and Data. Solved it.

Comment: Works, but not an option to promote since users will never do this.

Comment: True. This was a testing issue for me as a developer, not a production issue for end users.

Answer (score 1):

### You can handle it by setting different LoginBehavior

let loginManager = LoginManager()

loginManager.loginBehavior = .web

#### .native

: Logging in through the native Facebook app may be used.

#### .browser

: Attempts log in through the Safari.app or `SFSafariViewController`, if available.

#### .systemAccount

: Attempts log in through the Facebook account currently signed in through the the device Settings.

#### .web

: Attempts log in through a modal `WebView` pop up.